# How to Include a count(*) as additional result field of a query in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Given a table of players (users) with several fields. One of this is their rating with respect other players.

I'd like to implement via LINQ following SQL query:

```
SELECT p.*,
    (select COUNT(*) from Users where (Rating > p.Rating)) as Rank
FROM Users as p
ORDER BY p.Rating DESC
```

In other words, last field (RANK) should give the rank of each user with respect the others:

```
Id  Username  ... Rating     Rank
43  player41  ... 1002,333  0
99  player97  ... 1002      1
202 player200 ... 1002      1
53  player51  ... 1000,667  2
168 player166 ... 1000,667  2
56  player54  ... 1000      3
32  player30  ... 999,342   4
```

This attempt does not work:

```
var q = from u in Users
        orderby u.Rating descending
        group u by u.Id into g
        select new 
        { 
            MyKey = g.Key, 
            User = g.First(), 
            cnt = Users.Count(uu => uu.Rating > g.First().Rating) + 1 
        };
```

Just for your knowledge, note that the table `Users` is mapped to a EF entity named `User` with a 'NotMapped' `int?` field named Rank where I'd like to manually copy the rank:

```
class User {
    ...
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual int? Rank { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: _"This attempt does not work"_ What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want something like:

```
var rankedUsers = db.Users
    .Select(user => new
    {
        User = user,
        Rank = db.Users.Count(innerQueryUser => innerQueryUser.Rating > user.Rating)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Which will give you a list of users and their Rank as an anonymous type.
You'll then be able to do something like:

```
List<User> users = rankedUsers.Select(rankedUser=>
{
    rankedUser.User.Rank = rankedUser.Rank;
    return rankedUser.User;
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Query is extremely simple. This means I'm really basic with LINQ :-(. But what I really like is how you avoided the `foreach` for returning the list of users filled with their rank. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkFI,  There is a minor fix to apply. Line `rankedUser.User.Rank = user.Rank;` should be `rankedUser.User.Rank = rankedUser.Rank;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 var q = (from u in Users
         select new 
        {
           UserId = u.Id,
           UserObj = u,
           Rank = (from u1 in Users where u1.Rating>u.Rating select u1).Count()
        }).ToList();
```